# Java restores old variable value

Tags: java, android-fragments

In my application, I pass a list from one fragment to another. I want to use this list in this other fragment, which shouldn't be too difficult. In the `onCreateView` of this fragment I have this code:

```
userList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("userList");
```

This `userList` varies depending on the button the user has pressed in the previous fragment. It returns the correct ArrayList, but when I want to access the list further on in the class, the contents of the list suddenly have changed to those of the previous list that was loaded.

In the same fragment:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    FirebaseHelper.photoDelegate = this;
    FirebaseHelper.initializeMapMarkers(currentUser, false, false, null);
```

...the value of `userList` is still the same as it was in the `onCreateView`. When the fragment class receives a callback from `initializeMapMarkers`, the value has changed to the value it had the first time the fragment was called.

Some clarifying code:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, CallbackGroupUpdate,
    PhotoInterface {

private ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> userIDs;
private User currentUser;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    (...)

    userList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("userList"); // Get information of users in group
    currentUser = getArguments().getParcelable("currentUser"); // Get information of current user

    (...)

    return view;
}

(...)

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    (...)

    FirebaseHelper.photoDelegate = this;
    FirebaseHelper.initializeMapMarkers(currentUser, false, false, null);
```

Then `initializeMapMarkers` runs and calls callback function in `MapFragment` class:

```
@Override
public void initializeCurrentUserMarker(User userData) {

    (...)

    // Initialize markers for other users
    FirebaseHelper.getOtherUserMapMarkers(userList); < Value is still the same as in onCreateView }
```

Again: `FirebaseHelper`

```
public static void getOtherUserMapMarkers(final ArrayList<User> userList) {
    int i = 0;
    ArrayList<User> initializedUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (User user : userList) {
        i++;
        if (i == userList.size()) {
            initializeMapMarkers(user, true, true, initializedUsers);
        } else {
            initializeMapMarkers(user, true, false, initializedUsers);
        }
    }
}
```

After this, nothing is done anymore with the `userList`, so how could it be changed when the `MapFragment` receives another callback after this method?

Comment: an [MCVE] would help

Comment: I edited my question, hopefully it's somewhat clearer now

Comment: that fragment shows no references to userList nor how currentUser was obtained/created.

Comment: With the given code information, it is hard to tell what would be the problem. I can only guess some possible problems because the example shows only small part of the entire code.

Comment: All code where the variable is used is in the question now